# Mental Framework to Approach a Binary Search Variant

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary-search

I need some sort of mental framework that I can use to implement solutions requiring binary search. I am not sure what I am missing but I can not seem to come up with a solution on my own. Lets take the following problem as an example, but my issues are more general with problems involving binary search.

Objective: Given a non-negative integer `x`, compute and return the square root of `x` with its decimals truncated. Note, you can not use power or sqrt function.

Example:

- input = 8
- output = 2
- explanation, the square root of 8 is 2.82.., but we only care about whole number so return 2

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NGXR.png)

My current approach is to write down around 3-4 test cases, and apply the binary search that I am most familiar with. Documented by leetcode as "Template 1" https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/125/template-i/938/

Then I try to modify it so make those test cases pass. This feels like a very naive approach and is obviously not the way since I consistently fail to provide a solution because not all test cases pass, even for other binary search style problems.

```py
# passes x = 6, x = 4, x = 3. Fails x = 2, x = 7
class Solution:
    def mySqrt(self, x: int) -> int:
        
        if x == 0:
            return x
        if x == 1:
            return 1
        
        lo = 0
        hi = x-1
        
        while lo <= hi:
            mid = lo + (hi - lo)//2
            val = (mid + 1) * (mid + 1)
            
            if val < x:   # we are looking too low
                lo = mid + 1
            elif val > x:   # we are looking too high
                hi = mid - 1
            else:
                return mid + 1
            
        return mid + 1
```

- **What approach should be carried out to figure out these types of problems?**
- **Furthermore, I am having trouble of coming up with the invariant for this problem. What would it be?**

Comment: Unrelated to the original question but why are you using binary search for computing an integer square root? There's an algorithm exactly for that.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It's not a useful algorithm to computer the square root. This is a contrived problem imo. It's just for practicing binary type questions in order to properly apply its variants when it is actually useful to solve the problem at hand @AlexF

Comment: The loop invariant is `f(lo) <= x AND f(hi) >= x`. Your code does not maintain that invariant.

Comment: @user3386109 how do you arrive to that invariant? and what is the f?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but some of the details are wrong.  It looks like you aren't really understanding how binary search works.

Especially consider that comparing mid * mid to x can tell you if mid is too high, but it can't tell you if mid is too low, or just right.  That's OK.  You just have to be careful and use the information you get from the comparison, like this:

```
 mySqrt(x: int) -> int:
    lo = 0  # lowest possible answer
    hi = x  # highest possible answer

    while lo < hi:
        # we have not yet determined the answer
        # this guarantees lo <= mid-1 < mid <= hi
        # I wrote this line *after* writing the conditions below that
        # produce mid-1 and mid as new boundaries.
        mid = lo + (hi + 1 - lo)//2
        if mid*mid > x:
            # mid is too high
            hi = mid-1  # new highest possible answer
        else:
            # mid is not too high
            lo = mid    # new lowest possible answer
    # here hi = lo, so we know what the answer is
    return lo
```

That's it.

Note that if we had a "too low" test instead of a "too high" test, then we would get `mid` and `mid+1` as possible new boundaries, and we'd adjust the line where we set `mid` to ensure that both of these are in the `[lo,hi]` range, like `mid = lo + (hi-lo)//2`.

Comment: Do you have any insight into how exactly you came up with that solution? starting from the bounds and terminating conditions. I feel like I debug, see that it works beautifully, maybe gain some intuition from debugging if I am lucky, repeat it and somewhat memorize it, then still fail to come up with the details of the implementation on my end  next time the problem is a bit different, say, finding peak element in list. It would be extremely useful in hearing your though process behind that elegant solution. @MattTimmermans

Comment: I tried to do that with all the comments.  You use binary search when there is a range of possible answers, and you can check whether a guess is too low and/or too high. The termination condition is when the answer is no longer indeterminate -- highest possible <= lowest possible.  Everything else is just being careful -- make sure the range is actually reduced each iteration, and that it doesn't include any answers you've already ruled out.  Write it from scratch and know that it works, instead of trying to copy and modify.  This one looks so nice, because I've done it a million times.